# Visual Studio 2010 Create Project Installer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, deployment

I have built a simple project in Visual Studio 2010. It runs fine on my current computer, however when I bring it to another computer it complains about files not existing. For example, a .dll file and .NET 4.0.

How can I create a utility to install all the files?

I've tried many tutorials online including:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/12/14/building-setup-and-deployment-packages-in-vs-2010.aspx

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/how-to-create-an-installer-in-microsoft-visual-studio/

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231074-setup-and-deployment-in-visual-studio-2010/

http://syncor.blogspot.ca/2011/06/visual-studio-msi-installer.html

However, when I try to add a new project I don't have any of those options. Here is my 'Add New Project' screen:

[image: Add New Project Screen]

In the end I need an executable that I can give someone which will install the program with all dependencies. I feel like this is a process everyone who builds a program for anyone except themselves needs to do so it should be really simple. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't think the express edition comes with  Setup and Deployment Project. only the full version (not free) contains it.

Comment: Is there any way to create a deployable project without purchasing the full version?